# Detect IOS 8 with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ios

I have googled and and tried many ideas but they either mess up the entire site on all browsers, or they are really old, or they are javascript and not jQuery. I am exhausted.

Currently this works for detection IOS, but not a version:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);
    if (agentID) {

... do something here

    }
});
```

**How can I add just IOS 8 detection inside this so I can just create an html class "ios-8" "no-ios8" or equivalent.**

Comment: Just curious: Why do you need to target iOS 8 in particular?

Comment: "or they are javascript and not jQuery" -- jQuery is written in JavaScript, and it's perfectly acceptable to use a pure JS solution if it's the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: @SebastianWramba - because things that worked in earlier versions of IOS now don't work in IOS 8, such as weird stuff with position:fixed that were perfectly fine before.

Comment: @Palpatim - yes, but since I can't seem to figure it out when it's pure js since I am not so hot at either, better with jQuery but not great.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mobile Safari's UA string looks like this:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A405 Safari/600.1.4

(Source: http://whatsmyuseragent.com/)

So you could write a function like this. (**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/gaketu/1/edit)**)

```
var isIOS8 = function() {
  var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  return /(iphone|ipod|ipad).* os 8_/.test(deviceAgent);
}

alert("isIOS8: " + isIOS8());
```

Visit the demo page in a mobile safari browser, or webview app like iOS Chrome, to see it alert `true`.

Comment: Is this just for iphone or will it work on ipad too?

Comment: The regex above was limited to iphone. Edited to support iPhone, iPod, or iPad, as your original code did.

Comment: The regex above will not pick up the ipad mini because there are some chars between "ipad" and "os 8_". We are using /(iphone|ipod|ipad).*os 8_/ which seems to be working on our test-devices